# Prevent WordPress plugin from connecting to its server

Tags: plugins

I have a WordPress plugin which keeps sending and retrieving data to its server. Is it possible to block url of plugin such as api.plugindata.com.

Comment: How is the plugin sending it? Is it using WP APIs or Curl or file_get_contents? Have you contacted the plugin author? What problem does doing this solve for you? Context is very important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your `/etc/hosts` file you can add

> api.plugindata.com 127.0.0.1

or

> api.plugindata.com localhost

to route all traffic going to `api.plugindata.com` to your own machine.

---

If you don't have access to the file you can also search in the plugin source code where this domain occurs and either comment the code or maybe use a hook (if available) to prevent communicating.

Answer (score 1):

If the author of this plugin has not made this available by registering a filter or action hook, you can't do what you want without changing the plugin's source code, which will be overwritten with next update of the plugin.

If you are looking to block the url using server's settings, you should ask the question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Just to add: If the plugin authors use pluggable functions you can override those, e.g. via mu-plugins